# Is there a way to allow metamask to allow all transactions for a specific dapp

Tags: metamask

The metamask popup prompts me and ask me a confirmation each time i send a transaction from my dapp.

Is there a way to configure metamask in order to allow all transactions from my dapp, without having to confirm them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `.send()` while invoking method from javascript. I don't think metamask can help you in anyway to always allow transactions.

pseudo:

```
await <contractObject>.methods.<method_you_are_invoking_in_contract>
      .send({
             from: accounts[0],
             value: web3.utils.toWei(<amount_in_ether>, "ether"),
             gas: "1000000"
            });
```